# How to get context of class

Tags: android, firebase-mlkit

I have the following class and i try to get context so as to send an intent to another activity.

```
 public class CloudDocumentTextRecognitionProcessor
            extends VisionProcessorBase<FirebaseVisionCloudText> {

        public Context mContext;

        private FirebaseVisionCloudDocumentTextDetector detector;

public CloudDocumentTextRecognitionProcessor() {
            super();
            detector = FirebaseVision.getInstance().getVisionCloudDocumentTextDetector();
        }

        public CloudDocumentTextRecognitionProcessor(Context context) {

            this.mContext = context;

        }

        @Override
        protected Task<FirebaseVisionCloudText> detectInImage(FirebaseVisionImage image) {

            return detector.detectInImage(image);
        }


        @Override
        protected void onSuccess(
                @NonNull FirebaseVisionCloudText text,
                @NonNull FrameMetadata frameMetadata,
                @NonNull GraphicOverlay graphicOverlay) {

            graphicOverlay.clear();

            Intent i = new Intent(mContext, ResultActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            i.putExtra("key", text.getText());
            mContext.startActivity(i);


        }


    }
```

But i get an error in the line where i set the intent:

"Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference"

I ve also tried  MyApplication.getContext() instead of mContext, but with no results.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you already tried `Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ResultActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);` as well?

Comment: Cannot resolve method getApplicationContext(). but i tried mContext.getApplicationContext().   Still remains the problem..

Comment: Yes i get the error when i define the intent.    does not recognize "this"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have a setter for the mContext field and you can use the secondary constructor for the class that passes the context.
Initialize the class object from your activity like this:

```
CloudDocumentTextRecognitionProcessor imageProcessor = new CloudDocumentTextRecognitionProcessor(this);
```

or

```
CloudDocumentTextRecognitionProcessor imageProcessor = new CloudDocumentTextRecognitionProcessor(getApplicationContext());
```

Comment: @ktsakiris if it solved your problem mark this as the right answer

Answer (score 2):

This class does not inherit any Android component that has a Context, so you have to inject it yourself. You have to instantiate the class with the constructor that takes a Context as a parameter, and pass it in from an Activity or other Android component that has a context/access to the app context.

Something like (pseudo-code):

```
Class MyActivity
{
    ...
    imageProcessor = new CloudDocumentTextRecognitionProcessor(this);
    // or imageProcessor = new CloudDocumentTextRecognitionProcessor(this.getApplicationContext());
}
```

How to choose the context?

- If the `CloudDocumentTextRecognitionProcessor`instance is supposed to exist throughout the whole lifetime of your app, use `getApplicationContext()`;
- If the `CloudDocumentTextRecognitionProcessor`instance is guaranteed to only exist during the lifetime of the Activity, use `this`.